# Verify that $u, \; v$ are continuous in a neighborhood of $z=0$ and satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann Eqns at $z=0$. Show that $f'(0)$ does not exist.

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives, continuity, cauchy-riemann-equations

This is a question from a previous complex analysis qualifying exam that I'm working through to study for my own upcoming qual. I'm really struggling to know where to go with it and any help would be appreciated!

**Question (exact wording from the exam):**

Consider the function $f(z) = u(x,y) + iv(x,y)$, where

$$
u(x,y) = \frac{x^3 - y^3}{x^2 + y^2}, \quad v(x,y) = \frac{x^3 + y^3}{x^2+y^2}
$$

for $z=x+iy\neq 0$ and $u(0,0) = v(0,0) = 0$.

(a) Verify that $u, \; v$ are continuous in a neighborhood of $z=0$ and satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann Equations at $z=0$. 
(b) Show that $f'(0)$ does not exist.

**Why I'm struggling from the very start:**

(1) I know the epsilon-delta definition of continuity at a point. How do I apply this to a neighborhood of a point instead?

(2) When I try to apply the Cauchy-Riemann Equations,
$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}, \quad \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = -\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}
$$

these would be undefined when evaluated at $(x,y) = 0$. Am I supposed to take a limit perhaps?

(3) If I successfully do part (a), it seems that's supposed to ensure that a derivative of $f$ DOES exist at $z=0$, but the question asks to show the opposite.

Can someone please walk me through this problem?

Comment: I don't really get what you're asking in (1). Continuty and the limit involved already imply that you're interested in the neighborhood of $(0,0)$. The hole purpose of the exercise is that (2) is actually true everywhere. At $(0,0)$ you have to compute the partials via limit deffinition, because $u$ and $v$ are piecewise defined. In (3) you'll have to conclude that those partials are just derivatives along the coordinate axes, and in other directions they take different values! (try to graph them). Then the complex derivative does not exist (partials lack of continuity at $(0,0)$).

Comment: I think you missed a sign either in $u(x,y)$ or $v(x,y)$. Please check.

Comment: @xpaul You were correct. I’ve fixed it.

Comment: @Luciano I'm not sure what you mean with (1), but I've figured out (with help) that since it's clear that $u$ and $v$ are continuous away from zero, and are specifically defined to be zero at $(x,y) = (0,0)$, one needs only to consider the limit at $(x,y)\to(0,0)$ of the functions $u$ and $v$ to get continuity in a neighborhood of zero. The rest makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(0,0)&=&\lim_{\Delta x\to0}\frac{u(\Delta x,0)-u(0,0)}{\Delta x}=\lim_{\Delta x\to0}\frac{\Delta x}{\Delta x}=1\\
\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}(0,0)&=&\lim_{\Delta y\to0}\frac{v(\Delta y,0)-v(0,0)}{\Delta y}=\lim_{\Delta y\to0}\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta y}=1.
\end{eqnarray}
Similarly,
$$ \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}(0,0)=-\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}(0,0)=-1. $$
So the Cauchy-Riemann equations hold at $z=0$. Now for $\Delta z=\Delta x+i\Delta y$,
\begin{eqnarray}
f'(0)&=&\lim_{\Delta z\to0}\frac{f(\Delta z)-f(0)}{\Delta z}\\
&=&\lim_{\Delta x\to0, \Delta y\to 0}\frac{u(\Delta x,\Delta y)+iv(\Delta x,\Delta y)}{\Delta x+i\Delta y}\\
&=&\lim_{\Delta x\to0, \Delta y\to 0}\frac{\frac{\Delta x^3 - \Delta y^3}{\Delta x^2 + \Delta y^2}+i\frac{\Delta x^3 + \Delta y^3}{\Delta x^2+\Delta y^2}}{\Delta x+i\Delta y}.
\end{eqnarray}
For $\Delta y=k\Delta x$,
\begin{eqnarray}
f'(0)&=&\frac{(1-k^3)+i(1+k^3)}{(1+k^2)(1+ki)}
\end{eqnarray}
which depends on the value of $k$. So $f'(0)$ does not exists.